# Q: Can I update values of an entire column from a workflow?

Tags: list, workflow, column, updatelistitems

I'm using VBA to gather info based on their status. What I'd like to do is reset their status after the VBA operation is done. From my understanding, there is no way to update via Excel VBA. My only option is if there is a way to "batch" reset all the values within the "status" column back to "Not Ready" type of value.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Can VBA call a web service? If so, you could use that. Which version of SharePoint is this?

Comment: That's a good question, but I'm not sure. We're using 2010.

Comment: I think I am on to something... What do you mean 'to "batch" reset all the values within the "status" column back to "Not Ready" type of value.'? Do you mean reset all of the list items' status fields back to "Not Ready"?

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done with out of the box functionality, AFAIK. There is a free tool, called the HarePoint Workflow Scheduler. Once installed on the server, you can configure it to run on each item in a view. It can even work without views by providing the CAML query directly to the scheduler task.

http://www.harepoint.com/products/harepointworkflowscheduler/default.aspx

I am not affiliated with the product but have used it successfully on my sites.

Comment: teylyn, sorry for out topic. Do you think HarePoint can solve my question here? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92703/please-guide-me-on-create-a-sending-report-site-workflow

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so that SP Designer workflows  will able to perform batch update unless and untill all the item Eidted or Added simultaneously. If all the item added or Edited simultaneusly in a list than it is possible. Or you can update item programatically.
Pls check below links.
http://sharepointcore.blogspot.nl/2011/12/sharepoint-batch-updating-list-items.html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc404818%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: That looks great, however I failed to mention that I do not have access to Central Admin or any coding behind SharePoint, only SPD. I'm ok with just creating a manual workflow to reset a column, however I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I don't know whether this will work or not but you can create "status" column as Lookup column. lookup the value from another list and set the value of another list using your workflow. Once the value changed in another list it will reflect in all the items of the status column. You just give a try and let me know whether it work or not.

Comment: I created two Lists List A and List B. Suppose in your case List B is taking value from excel and in List B just create a column Status lookup column which will take value from Column "Status Value" of List A. Now I written a workflow  on List A which will simply set the current item value to Not ready which will reflect in all the items of List B.
Workflow:-
Set <column name> to Not Ready